# Symfony: how to configure default options for all routes?

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, symfony-routing

**Can I configure the following option in a single place rather than per route?**

In my `routing.yml` file every route has:

```
options:
    utf8: true
```

Because of

> In Symfony 3.2, there is no need to explicitly set the utf8 option. As soon as Symfony finds a UTF-8 character in the route path or requirements, it will automatically turn on the UTF-8 support. However, this behavior is deprecated and setting the option will be required in Symfony 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Annotations** it's possible in `routing.yml` to configure default options for all routes defined in `AppBundle/Controller/` like this:

```
app_bundle:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    schemes:  "https"
    options: { utf8: true }
```

Using **Yaml** you could try putting this directive at the very first place in `routing.yml`:

```
app_name:
    path: ^/
    #path: ^/* <-- another attempt to include all routes after the first /
    options: { utf8: true }
    #host: <-- maybe you should specify this and/or other params depending by your needs.
```